# Weekly Data is not Returned using Between in SQLite

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, android-fragments

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    this.db = db;
    db.execSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE `Transaction` (" +
            "_id integer primary key autoincrement," +
            "`categoryID` INT NOT NULL , " +
            "`incomeAmount` INT NOT NULL, " +
            "`expenseAmount` INT NOT NULL, " +
            "`note` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , " +
            "`transactionDate` INT NOT NULL, " +
            "`repeatType` INT NOT NULL  , " +
            "`transactionType` BOOLEAN NOT NULL )"
    );
}
public Cursor readDatabaseTransactionWeekly(Date date){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
    cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
    cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());

    Date startWeek = cal.getTime();
    Calendar nextWeelCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    nextWeelCal.setTime(cal.getTime());
    nextWeelCal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH,1);
    Date nextWeek = nextWeelCal.getTime();
    Log.d(TAG, "readDatabaseTransactionWeekly: "+startWeek+" to "+nextWeek+"");
    this.db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor transactionRecordWeekly = this.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM `Transaction` WHERE transactionDate BETWEEN '"+startWeek+"' AND '"+nextWeek+"'",null);
    transactionRecordWeekly.moveToFirst();
    return transactionRecordWeekly;
}

public Cursor readDatabaseTransactionMonthly(Date date){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
    cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
    cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    Date startMonth = cal.getTime();
    Calendar nextMonthCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    nextMonthCal.setTime(cal.getTime());
    nextMonthCal.add(Calendar.MONTH,1);
    Date nextMonth = nextMonthCal.getTime();
    this.db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor transactionRecordMonthly = this.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM `Transaction` WHERE transactionDate BETWEEN '"+startMonth+"' AND '"+nextMonth+"'",null);
    transactionRecordMonthly.moveToFirst();
    return transactionRecordMonthly;
}
```

I am trying to read data from SQLite in Andoroid on Weekly and Monthly Bases and I am using SQLite BETWEEN Statement. But It's not working as expected. The weekly section doesnot return any data at all while Monthly works fine does not show data of current week. I looked into 4 other stackoverflow question but couldnot solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the type of "transactionDate" field to "long" and then inserted the dates into the database by converting dates in milliseconds. This is the solution that worked for me and maybe it's not a good one but it worked. I am posting that it may help anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH does not do what you expect.
Try adding 7 days instead.

Comment: Tried adding 7 days in Calender.DAY_OF_Month but not output again.

Comment: Anyway this is the Start and End Dates of week with Calender.WEEK_OF_Month which looks fine.                                                                                                  Sun Jun 24 00:00:00 GMT+05:00 2018 to Sun Jul 01 00:00:00 GMT+05:00 2018

Answer (score 0):

`cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());` sets the date to Monday 18 June

Comment: Tried that before as well. But it App stops unexpectedly and it shows this error. Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
     (near "Jun": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM `Transaction` WHERE transactionDate BETWEEN Sun Jun 24 00:00:00 GMT+05:00 2018 AND Sun Jul 01 00:00:00 GMT+05:00 2018)

Comment: Where? nextWeelCal.setTime(cal.getTimeInMillis()); iI cahnged it here but IDE shows error since nextWeek is Date Type.

Comment: No output again. I cahnged startWeek and nextWeek to long. But still nothing. :-(

Comment: changing transactionDate to DATE is also not working.

Comment: Can you provide some code of how you store the date in db?

Comment: String qry="INSERT INTO `Transaction` (`categoryID`, `incomeAmount`,`expenseAmount`, `note`, `transactionDate`, `repeatType`, `transactionType`) VALUES ("+transaction.getCategoryID()+", "+transaction.getIncomeAmount()+", "+transaction.getExpenseAmount()+", '"+transaction.getNote()+"', '"+transaction.gettransactionDate()+"', "+transaction.getRepeatType()+", "+tType+")";
Here is the Query to insert data into database

Comment: And what is gettransactionDate()? Is it int from milliseconds of a date?

Comment: It's returning Date type

Comment: Everything working fine for the Daily Fragement as you can see it shows Data as it should. The only problem is with Weekly and Monthly.

Comment: With your code weekly means you get transactions from 18 June to 25 June 00:00:00. How many transactions are in this range?

Comment: With weekly code means the dates are from 24 june to 1 July and there are 6 transactions in this range. But it shows none in weekly and shows 3 in Monthly.

Comment: this is the Start and End Dates of week. Sun Jun 24 00:00:00 GMT+05:00 2018 to Sun Jul 01 00:00:00 GMT+05:00 2018

Comment: No Sir, The Week starts from Sunday according to my Applicaation and the  the Start and End Dates of week are Sun Jun 24 00:00:00 GMT+05:00 2018 to Sun Jul 01 00:00:00 GMT+05:00 2018

Comment: Changing First Day of Week to Monday also doesn't work.

Comment: It's a matter of settings i suppose. Anyway when dealing with dates in SQLite it is recommended as you could find in other SO posts to use yyyy-MM-dd format and store them as TEXT.

Comment: Hmm... Thanks. I shall look into that.